# How does Market Samurai and Long Tail Pro handle retrieving the top 10 Google search results for a keyword?

Tags: google-api, google-search, google-search-api

I'm curious to know how Market Samurai, Long Tail Pro and other software handle retrieving the top 10 Google search results and not running into limits. It appears that these software packages use the users own Google account. Google Custom Search limits users to 100 queries per day (the free limit) but people tend to do keyword research on hundreds or even thousands of keywords per day and don't pay any additional amounts to Google.

Are they paying extra for this service, are they using a different API (perhaps the Adwords API?) or are they scraping the Google search results page (violation of TOS)? Really would like to know! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i have done this in one of my project (in java).

this is very simple, in java there is one library call [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/) by using this library you can send get request to google, for example:

```
https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=<your url encoded search term>
```

this will return you an HTML code of google search result with your own term.

using Jsoup u can find specific HTML tag with specific class or id. this concept helps you to extract url link, title and description from google search result.

for working example check [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/jsoup-send-search-query-to-google/), in that example you can extract google serach result links with custom search term.

i hope this will help you.